# A class of Global Variables

Tags: c#, class, global-variables

Recently I am working a server that transfers commands and data and in my global variables, I have a 100 constants that I use through out my program for communication protocols. Is there a way I can make a class of global variables and then access that class when needed?

Comment: You can make enumerations unless the values need to change during runtime.

Comment: yes you can , make the class to be static , then you can access this class (if it is on the same namespace).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to create a class and mark it as `static`:

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static int GlobalInt;
    public static float GlobalFloat;
}
```

You'll be able to access these anywhere in your program.

If you do not want anyone to be able to edit these values, you could mark them with the `const` keyword:

```
public const int GlobalInt = 15;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a static class and mark your fields with `const` keyword, it's implicitly `static` and you won't be able to overwrite them by accident.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestions above, is there any chance that these "constants" might change in the future?  The reason I ask is that you mentioned they were communication protocols.  If its things like addresses, ports or anything else that might change, consider using the static class and on that class use a static constructor to read the values from the configuration or have the static properties of that class just refer to the configuration.  You don't want a firewall change to force you to have to recompile your code.

If a value has no chance of changing, it should be a const.